# How to update a row in DB without overwriting the existing data with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table which stores the user's interested topics along with the user id and topic id. The table will look like

```
Topic name     topic id     User-id
   Sports         1             1
   Education      2             3
   Family         3             1
```

What i want to do is when a new user , say user-id '3' adds his interest as topic sports , then the first row should look like this

```
Topic name     topic id     User-id
   Sports         1             1,3
```

When i try to update it overwrites the whole column like

```
Topic name     topic id     User-id
   Sports         1             3
```

What is the right approach to do this ?

Comment: The right approach is to use Many-To-Many relationship.

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO NO NO AAARRRggghhhhh. never store anything as a comma seperated list in a single column of a relational database. **There be madness**

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to use `Many-To-Many` relationship:

**Tables:**

```
users (id, ....);
topics (id, ....);
topic_user (topic_id, user_id);
```

**PHP:**

```
class User extends Model {

    public function topics() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topic');
    }
}
```

and :

```
class Topic extends Model {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

For more details please refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships.

I hope this will help.